# groovy or java: how to retrieve a block of comments using regex from /** ***/?

Tags: java, regex, groovy

This might be a piece of cake for java experts. Please help me out:

I have a block of comments in my program like this:

```
/********* 
block of comments - line 1
line 2
.....
***/
```

How could I retrieve "block of comments" using regex?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
    String str =
        "some text\n"+
        "/*********\n" +
        "block of comments - line 1\n" +
        "line 2\n"+
        "....\n" +
        "***/\n" +
        "some more text";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\\*+(.*?)\\*+/", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    if (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

(`DOTALL` says that the `.` in the pattern should also match new-line characters)
Prints:

```
block of comments - line 1
line 2
....
```

Comment: messes up if you put /* in a string in the code. NOONE should do that but im just saying.

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("/\\*[^\\r\\n]*[\\r\\n]+(.*?)[\\r\\n]+[^\\r\\n]*\\*+/", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This works because comments can't be nested in Java.

It is important to use a reluctant quantifier (`.*?`) or we will match everything from the first comment to the last comment in a file, regardless of whether there is actual code in-between.

`/\*` matches `/*`

`[^\r\n]*` matches whatever else is on the rest of this line.

`[\r\n]+` matches one or more linefeeds.

`.*?` matches as few characters as possible.

`[\r\n]+` matches one or more linefeeds.

`[^\r\n]*` matches any characters on the line of the closing `*/`.

`\*/` matches `*/`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the multi-line issues, but it were all on one line, you could do this:

```
^\/\*.*\*\/$
```

That breaks down to:

```
^ start of a line
\/\*+ start of a comment, one or more *'s (both characters escaped)
.* any number of characters
\*+\/ end of a comment, one or more *'s (both characters escaped)
$ end of a line
```

By the way, it's "regex" not "regrex" :)

Comment: I think both your \\* need to be \\*+

Comment: @Ethan Thanks. Didn't realize that those extra *'s shouldn't be matched.